# How do you insert a code block inside a code block to give an example in Markdown?

Tags: markdown

When I try to insert a code block inside a code block, it doesn't work as expected. For example, I want to show that making code blocks is like

```markdown
![alt text](link)
```

When I insert this into a code block, the result is

````markdown
```markdown
![alt text](link)
````

Comment: What are you using to generate this "result"?

Comment: Markdown. I tried to make notes for myself in Jupyter about Markdown, but I encountered this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm reasonably certain that code blocks in Markdown cannot be embedded within other code blocks—at least not with pure Markdown. The Markdown system of backticks is, in the HTML interpretation, generating a set of `<pre><code></code></pre>` tags.

That presents a possible alternative to using the triple backticks: You could instead use `<pre><code>` elements nested inside backticks. This appears to work on Stack Overflow, although I'm not certain about other Markdown interpreters.

For example:

```
<pre><code></pre></code>
```

I'm not 100% certain what you're looking to accomplish, so feel free to comment here if you have some clarifying details. I am more than willing to revise my answer to better assist.

Comment: I'll check first if this works in Jupyter Notebook.